# Postfix SMTP SSL config: Can't send email but can receive it with SSL

Tags: email, ubuntu-12.04, ssl, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to finish configuring my postfix/dovecot mail server that sits behind my home's router/firewall.  I'm on Mint/Ubuntu 12.04.

I'm close. I can connect/retrieve emails via SSL but can only send email from a client when not using SSL, just username/password.

If I attempt an SSL connection with the "smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes" in /etc/postfix/main.cf and SSL enabled on my client I can't send.

Below are some of what I think are the (modified) relevant lines from the log with a few comments. I am coming in on odd port number.. My cert is older and the CN does not match the server any longer.  (But if this were an issue why would I be able to IMAP retrieve using them?)

```
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: connection established
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: master_notify: status 0
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: name_mask: resource
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: name_mask: software
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: connect from router[XXX.XX.180.81]
```

> I would expect a connection from localhost, not my public IP.. Not sure what's happening here.

```
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 220 ghost.domain.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]:  router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]:  router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]:  router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: smtp_get: EOF
...
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3342]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from router[XXX.XX.180.81]
```

> Apparent end of first attempt
>
> Next attempt actually passes certificate information but ultimately fails.

```
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 220 ghost.domain.net ESMTP Postfix 
(Ubuntu)
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]:
```

> Confused by the line above.. 'imac.home' is email client's machine...

```
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: match_list_match: router: no match
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: match_list_match: XXX.XX.180.81: no match
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-ghost.domain.net
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-PIPELINING
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-SIZE 10240000
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-VRFY
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-ETRN
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-STARTTLS
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250-8BITMIME
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: > router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 250 DSN
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]:  router[XXX.XX.180.81]: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: setting up TLS connection from router[XXX.XX.180.81]
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: router[XXX.XX.180.81]: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: auto_clnt_open: connected to private/tlsmgr
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: send attr request = seed
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: send attr size = 32
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: status
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: input attribute name: status
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: input attribute value: 0
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: seed
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: input attribute name: seed
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: input attribute value: CYbyt+Fx2lpkfU7NordArB5Snqm93U4t5J/YuWwf2xA=
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: private/tlsmgr: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: input attribute name: (end)
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: read from 21104A00 [21110E00] (11 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: read from 21104A00 [21110E00] (11 bytes => 11 (0xB))
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: 0000 16 03 01 00 a4 01 00 00|a0 03 01
```

> Cert data

```
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: 009d - 
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client hello A
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write certificate A
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write key exchange A
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: write to 21104A00 [2111E7B8] (1455 bytes => 1455 (0x5AF))
```

> Certificate data

```
          
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: 05ac - 
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: read from 21104A00 [21110E03] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: read from 21104A00 [21110E03] (5 bytes => 0 (0x0))
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept:failed in SSLv3 read client certificate A
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: SSL_accept error from router[XXX.XX.180.81]: lost connection
```

...

```
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: lost connection after STARTTLS from router[XXX.XX.180.81]
Oct 18 22:13:02 ghost postfix/smtpd[3339]: disconnect from router[XXX.XX.180.81]
```

I'm sort of at a loss as to what to try next.

Hubert. Thank you for the clues. I did not have a the CA file path enabled.  I've done that as well as transition to new cert files but the error remains - a sudden disconnect.

Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf file (with edits)

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete
# version

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

# smtp is OUTBOUND from POSTFIX #
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/verizon
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# Scott's Stuff
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

# General
relayhost = [127.0.0.1]:50025

####################
myhostname = ghost.domain.net
mydomain = ghost.domain.net
myorigin = $myhostname
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain
#relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
#mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
# myshost
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
#smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ghost.domain.net.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/ghost.domain.net.crt
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ca.crt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

# Unique
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
inet_protocols = ipv4
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
#-auth
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium

##
#smtpd_sasl_application_name = smtpd
#smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
#smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer.

My email client is Apple Mail, which only supports SSL not TLS.  For whatever reason, this would cause dropped connections between Apple Mail and my server and it would disconnect. This also explains why postfix was always confused by the invalid commands --"???".

So I tested from my android phone using STARTTLS and it worked fine.  In order to let my home computer still connect I updated my server to not required TLS prior to SASL in /etc/postfix/main.cf.  I figure I can do this safely since I'm at home behind router & firewall.

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no

Maybe the OS X update I'm about to install will work. :)

Yeah. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to post your main.cf file to help you. 
At least the following should by in it for TLS to work. Of course you need a valid certificate and key.

```
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/xxx.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/server/xxx.crt
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Adding

```
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
```

will help you to understand what is going wrong

Comment: Thanks Hubert. I did not have the CA path enabled. I added that and updated my cert paths to current certs/keys.  Unfortunately, that didn't address this particular issue though.. I get the same error.  main.cf has been added above. Thanks!